# Adding icons to menu items in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I try to set an icon to menuitem, So I find that the attribute icon is supported, but No change happen when I change its value.

I want to know if it is still supported by menuitem in odoo v7/8. If not, how to add an icon to a menu item?

**Edit:**

I try to customize the view of the menu in odoo. So I override the template that render the menu in "webClient_templates.xml" from web module like this:

```
<template id="my_menu_link" inherit_id="web.menu_link">
  <span position="replace">
     <span class="oe_menu_text">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        <t t-esc="menu['name']"/>
     </span>
  </span>
</template>
```

Likely, all the menu items will have the same icon (i.e. fa-check) from font-awesome lib. 
Now, I try to add a specific icon for each menu item, that I can define it somehow in the xml description of menuitem as a kind of attribute or anything else, and retrieve it like this:

```
<i t-attrs-class="menu['icon']"></i>
```

I tried to use icon attribute of menuitem, even if it's deprecated, but menu['icon'] is not recognized in the template level.

Please any suggestions ?

Comment: What did you actually do to resolve your problem? Did you read the Documentation?

Comment: Actually, I extended "web.menu" and "web.menu_secondary" templates in webclientTemplate from web module, and I customize the displaying of menu elements.

Comment: I don't know if this question is still unanswered, but I'm using odoo-12 now and the icon field is still on the ir.ui.menu model, but the exact name is "web_icon", so did you try to entre developper mode to see the field name? Maybe `<i t-attrs-class="menu['web_icon']"></i>` works... (I didn't tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK displaying icons in menu items is deprecated and does not work on the web client. Probably the to achieve you would need to create a module for the web client extending it with that capability.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Actually, I extended "web.menu" and "web.menu_secondary" templates in webclientTemplate from web module, and I customize the displaying of menu elements. But, I'm blocked on how to get additional information dynamically from xml file. I mean if I want to get the information of the icon from the xml declaration of menuitem, any additional attribute (like class...) is not accepted, so I can't define my icon from xml even if I override the displaying. Any Idea in this case, please?

Comment: You should write a question explaining what you tried and where exactly you are blocked...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using odoo v12 now, and there is also an unused field for icons on ir.ui.menu model.

I managed to show icons on backend's menus, here are the difference with your code:

- The icon field is named `web_icon`, it may be specific to v10+ , I don't have a v8 to verify this.
- The templating syntax to set attributes is `t-att-<name>` and not `t-attrs-<name>`
- And most important: the menus in backend are generated using javascript, so the templates to modify are to find in `web/static/src/xml/menu.xml`
- There are 3 places to add an `<i>` markup in 2 templates:

  - `<t t-name="Menu.link">`

    - Line 47: `<span><i t-att-class="menu.web_icon"></i> <t t-esc="menu.name"/></span>`
    - Line 59: `<span><i t-att-class="menu.web_icon"></i> <t t-esc="menu.name"/></span>`
  - `<t t-name="Menu.sections">`

    - Line 81: `<i t-att-class="second_level_menu.web_icon"></i> <t t-esc="second_level_menu.name"/>`

The data to set in menu's icon field is the whole font-awesome CSS classes:
`fa fa-check`

This is good if you add more icons sets, you won't need to modify again the templates.
But if you want to force the usage of font-awesome, or want to use another icon set like font-awesome solid (using `fas` class), you can use this markup in templates:

`<i t-attf-class="fas fa-#{menu.web_icon}"></i>`
(note `t-attf-<name>` to use "attribute function")

And so the data in the field will be only `check`...

And finally, the best should be to create a module to inherit the templates and make this modification against modifying it directly as I did...
And also add some more CSS styling to align icon and text correctly (here icons are not the same sized).